# UI BootStrap - Multiple modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I'm working with a custom angular directive at my work that implements the angular ui bootstrap service to show a modal on the screen. I was just wondering if it's possible/wise to open up a second modal to display a validation error over the first modal. I know I could just use the JS .Alert function (or some angular version of it), but don't prefer the look. Just wanted to give this a try first.

Comment: Yes you can. I use angular-confirm which shows a modal as a confirmation message and it is usable when you have a modal opened.

Comment: `display a validation error over the first modal`yes, you can have a stack of modals open concurrently, but it's cumbersome and annoying, you can use a [tooltip per input to show validation errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726105/how-to-show-form-input-errors-using-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-tooltip) when they occur